# Running Selenium Tests in Virtual PC

Tags: selenium, nunit, virtual-pc, rc

I am creating test scripts in Visual Studio IDE using Selenium RC and
executing them thru NUnit. In order to run these tests on Virtual PC,
what would I need to do.

What all would I need to have on the Virtual machines? Only NUnit or
even Selenium?

If anybody has any experience setting this up and executing the test I
would appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

When setting up virtual machines all that you need is the browsers that you want to test with and Selenium RC. NUnit only needs to be on the machine that is running the test and not on every machine.

Then you make sure that your machines are always accessible by a name or a IP. If you can't gaurantee that then I suggest that you set up Selenium Grid. You don't need to run your tests in parallel with Grid you can also use it as an infrastructure tool to manage where the RC instances are. I have a tutorial [here](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/selenium_grid_as_infrastructural_tool.htm) that explains how you can set it up.

Comment: thanks, I'll try this and come back with more question if I can't still figure it out.